# Docker swarm load balancing using HTTP 503

Tags: docker, load-balancing, swarm

For a project, I would like to create a docker swarm with nodes/replicas using GPUs.

Since the default way to do load balancing is *round robin* (and according to [this link](https://www.nginx.com/blog/docker-swarm-load-balancing-nginx-plus/) load balancing takes place on TCP layer 4),

I would like to know if it is possible to make the balancer aware of a response of HTTP 503 (Service Unavailable)?
which means: if a node/replica has too less GPU memory for this request and hence responds with HTTP 503, the balancer should pass the request to the next node/replica in the round, until it is accepted (with any response <500)

Can this be done, and if not, is there a way to create a similar behaviour?

Comment: similar issue at GitHub https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24900

Comment: you can implement this logic by yourself by introducing your own load balancer which can be configured with such rules

Comment: Sounds good,
could you please give me a link to more information how to create my own load-balancer for docker swarm?
All I have found is some general info about load-balancing

Answer (score 1):

You can try to define your services as `global` to get only one running service per node.

Then we can use `traefik` (or similar load balancer) to configure load balancing logic:

- configure [health check](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/services/#health-check) for your service in order to monitor for 503 errors
- also you can consider using [weights](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/services/#weighted-round-robin-service) to more properly load balance your jobs

There are more "complex" solutions such as [HAproxy](https://www.haproxy.com), [kong proxy](https://konghq.com/kong/) or [consul](https://www.consul.io).

You can reconsider your architecture as well and transform it to the queue instead of request/response. So, the request will return a job id and you can take the results later after the job will be handled.

Another option is to implement proxy logic in a language you are comfortable with to handle 503 errors to proxy requests to other nodes.

I think the queue logic sounds more appropriate for the case you have described (albeit just barely).

Comment: As I would like to add several GPUs to a PC and create - at least - 1 worker instance per GPU, I suppose the solution to define a service as _global_ would not work well.